# Median dax function in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Does the medianx function work the same as averagex in Power Bi Dax?

Example Dataset:
account#  123,456,893,333
error count   5,6,2,11

Average should be 6
Median should be 5.5

When I use the below function to calculate my average error count per account it works perfectly fine.

```
Average(error count vs ID) = 
AVERAGEX(
   KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Device'[account# ])),
   CALCULATE(COUNTA('Device'[error count]))
)
```

But when I try and calculate my median count per account I get no output. How do I go by fixing this.

```
Medianx(error count vs ID) = 
MEDIANX(
   KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Device'[account# ])),
   CALCULATE(COUNTA('Device'[error count]))
)
```

Comment: What is the reason for KEEPFILTERS? And yes, it works the same way.

Comment: My understanding is so that the code knows to seperate error count by each account number

Comment: The first row its like a filter for CALCULATE(), So it counts value for each unique 'Device'[account# ] and a Blank Value also if you have. It can be different behavior when it gets blank()

Comment: I think I figured out my issue I had too many blanks so the median function was working properly it just so happened that my median value was a blank

Comment: Great, just interesting can you check your measures without KEEPFILTERS(), and let me know if it's any difference?

Comment: Still works without it

Comment: @Peter Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Please test this, and let me know If It works for you:

```
Average(error count vs ID) =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Device[account#] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Device[error count] ) )
)
```

And now median measure is like this:

```
Medianx(error count vs ID) =
MEDIANX (
    VALUES ( Device[account#] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Device[error count] ) )
)
```

If we test them, they return like this:

```
Full_Result_Table_Code=
ROW (
    "Average(error count vs ID)",
        AVERAGEX (
            VALUES ( Device[account#] ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Device[error count] ) )
        ),
    "Medianx(error count vs ID)",
        MEDIANX (
            VALUES ( Device[account#] ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Device[error count] ) )
        )
)
```

Resulting ScreenShot:

[image: FGD]